# Passing electrical current through magnets

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-circuits

I have a very simple setup with an LED, a battery, some wires, and two magnets:

```
  ┌──LED──┐
Magnet    │
  ╎       │
Magnet    │
  └ +9V- ─┘
```

I am trying to get the electrical current to flow through the magnets so that the LED lights up. However, I am unsuccessful. From what I have read, magnets are very poor conductors––if not insulators.

My goal is for the electrical current to flow through the magnets so that the LED can light up while the magnets are attracted to each other but not necessarily touching.

Is it possible for electricity to flow through the circuit even when the magnets are not actually touching?

If so, would I need a magnet that is also a conductor? Does such a magnet exist?

Comment: You can't have it both ways. The circuit you drew shows a wire connection between the two magnets, yet your text talks of a gap between them. Which is it?!?

Comment: @MaxW, that dashed line is meant to signify that there isn't actually a wire there but that the circuit is complete.

Comment: That's my point. If there is an air gap then the circuit isn't complete. So is there (a) a wire between the magnets, or (b) an air gap?

Comment: @MaxW, there is an air gap. Are you saying that it is impossible for the LED to light up if there is an air gap?

Comment: Yes, if there is an air gap then it is impossible to get a continuous current flow.

Comment: @MaxW, if the two magnets are touching, would the circuit be completed, or would the magnets' magnetic field mess up the electron flow of the circuit?

Comment: It depends on what the magnets are made of. For instance a soft iron bar magnet would conduct. "Rubberized" magnets wouldn't conduct. If the magnet was conductive then the magnetic field would not stop the current flow.

Comment: Re, "My goal is for...current to flow...[when] the magnets are attracted to each other _but not necessarily touching._" Is there a reason why it has to be two magnets? A [_reed switch_](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01NBPDU04/) will close a circuit when a magnet comes near (but not necessarily touching), and open the circuit again when the magnet is removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Is it possible for electricity to flow through the circuit even when the magnets are not actually touching?**

No.

Air is pretty much non-conducting (for the range of voltages and currents available with a typical PP3 9V battery)

The presence of a magnetic field is insufficient, by itself, to cause a current to flow through normal air (with proviso as above, and assuming magnetic fields produced by magnets found in typical retail stores).

> **would I need a magnet that is also a conductor?**

You need a conductor in the gap between the magnets.

> **Does such a magnet exist?**

Conductive magnets do exist. Many commonly available small neodymium magnets have a conductive coating.

[Random example](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Magnetic-Electrical-Connector-Pair-/291330796346?hash=item43d4ab2b3a:g:gX0AAMXQatBSblNW)

Comment: A neodymium magnet coated in nickel would work, right?

Comment: Nickel is about a fifth as conductive as copper but, yes, you can use it to pass electrical current.

Comment: Would coating some magnets in [this](https://www.amazon.com/11-Paper-Copper-Metallic-Qty/dp/B007BS4CIA/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1479775128&sr=8-1&keywords=copper%2Bpaper&th=1) work well?

Comment: Does anybody here remember AlNiCo?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alnico

Answer (score 0):

This is a follow-up clarification.
I actually disassembled a wireless logitect computer mouse with this kind of set-up.
The mouse was operated with a 1.5V AA battery.
The scroll wheel has 2 parallel magnets (like sandwich breads) but no any wire connected to it.
On the PCB, just a little far from the scroll wheel, there’s a small wind coils.
When I removed the scroll wheel, the mouse can’t be operated. However, when I put another magnet (not the scroll wheel) as a replacement for the scroll wheel, the mouse can be operated again.
I am not sure how electromagnetism or the magnets actually completes the circuit.

Comment: "When I removed the scroll wheel..." Maybe you created a condition that the firmware in the mouse was not designed to cope with. It would be surprising if removal of the scroll wheel impacted any other part of the mouse's electronic _hardware._